# How to find intersection points in a given voronoi diagram

Tags: matlab, voronoi

I'm trying to code an algorithm where the code finds the intersection points in a voronoi diagram. How do I get started?

I know only how to plot the voronoi diagram.

Below is an example.

**Coordinates of the blue circle's intersection points**

[image]

code from the voronio function's documentation

```
x = gallery('uniformdata',[1 10],0);

y = gallery('uniformdata',[1 10],1);

voronoi(x,y)
```

The code should detect any type of graph's intersection points and not just the results from the example code.

Comment: Please format your post appropriately

Comment: Are you asking how to obtain the vertices of the output of the `voronoi` function, or are you asking how to detect vertices in a rendered graph (i.e. from a bitmap)?

Comment: @CrisLuengo ive figured it out! It was the voronoin function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
[vx,vy] = voronoi(x,y)
```

for the Voronoi edges, or

```
[v,c] = voronoin([x(:) y(:)])
```

to also get the connectivity with each cell.

This is basically copy-paste from the [respective Matlab documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/voronoi.html).